# How to use spring transaction manager in case of dynamic data source?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have a scenario where datasource are dynamically created using `Datasource Factory`. So depending upon who accesses the system, DatasourceFacory(custom datasource factory) returns a corresponding `datasource`.

Now, with this strategy, how do I maintain Spring Transaction? Using a `@Transactional` annotation needs a fixed datasource with transaction manager configured.

I would like to continue to use `@Transactional` in a service method and not worry about having to maintain transaction myself.

I would think that I would have to extend some spring class and inject the datasource when the system starts.

I am using Spring and `JdbcTemplate` in my project. No Hibernate. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See https://mdeinum.wordpress.com/2007/01/05/one-application-per-client-database/ . The post is about multi tenancy but would work in this situation to.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `AbstractRoutingDataSource` to link it with your transaction manager, this kind of datasource allows you use different datasources choosing them in runtime.

After that spring handles the transaction properly. You can check this kind of DataSource in the Spring Documentation.

The other option is has different transactionManagers.

Answer (score 0):

For no-xml lovers

```
@Bean(name = "mysqldatasource1")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(classname);
    dataSource.setUrl(url);
    dataSource.setUsername(usernmae);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean(name = "mySqlJdbcTemplate1")
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate();
    jdbcTemplate.setDataSource(dataSource());
    return jdbcTemplate;
}

@Bean(name="mysqlTransaction1") 
@Autowired
DataSourceTransactionManager tm1(@Qualifier ("mysqldatasource") DataSource datasource) {
    DataSourceTransactionManager txm  = new DataSourceTransactionManager(datasource);
    return txm;
}
@Bean(name = "mysqldatasource2")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(classname);
    dataSource.setUrl(url);
    dataSource.setUsername(usernmae);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean(name = "mySqlJdbcTemplate2")
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate();
    jdbcTemplate.setDataSource(dataSource());
    return jdbcTemplate;
}

@Bean(name="mysqlTransaction2") 
@Autowired
DataSourceTransactionManager tm1(@Qualifier ("mysqldatasource2") DataSource datasource) {
    DataSourceTransactionManager txm  = new DataSourceTransactionManager(datasource);
    return txm;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create multiple Transaction Managers with different datasources and then access them in `@Transactional` annotation as follows:

```
 <bean id="txManager1" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource1"/>
    <qualifier value="txManager1"/>
 </bean>
```

Access it as:

```
 @Transactional("txManager1")
```

Similarly,

```
 <bean id="txManager2" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource2"/>
    <qualifier value="txManager2"/>
 </bean>
```

Access it as:

```
 @Transactional("txManager2")
```

As there can be only one annotation-driven TxManager, do not forget to remove this:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

Comment: Well, different datasource are dynamic . So same service when a user logs in can be using datasource_1 while another another user can use datasource_2 . so how can we use we define transactional manager . How do I know on the run time which transaction manager to use ?

Comment: How are you creating the datasource beans?

Comment: @Santosh why are you trying to change the datasource based on logged in user?

Comment: Sorry its not changing datasource .  It switching between datasource . we have multiple schemas configured and each user has data into its own schema . So based on user , we will have to use appropriate datasource .